# Listing recently used glassware

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Is there any way to get a list of the glassware the user has recently used? Kind of listing of recent apps you find on Android phones and tablets?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in feature like the task manager on your phone.

But you could create a service that repeatedly the recent tasks using the ActivityManager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks(int,int)

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> taskList = activityManager.getRecentTasks(10,0);
```

You can use this information to publish and update a LiveCard to create your task manager on your own.